# Uncaught ReferenceError: FixedColumns is not defined

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm following the examples to use FixedColumns.

```
var oTable4 = $('#example').dataTable( {
            "sScrollY": "300px",
            "sScrollX": "100%",
            "sScrollXInner": "150%",
            "bScrollCollapse": true,
            "bPaginate": false
        } );
        new FixedColumns( oTable4 );
```

I get the following error which means I've made some error initializing it...

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: FixedColumns is not defined
```

Is FixedColumn a seperate plugin?

I'm using jQuery 1.9.1.

Comment: I don't use `dataTable` but `FixedColumns` is listed as plugin there. So i think depending if you have a _full featured_ build or not you would need to load the js file for `FixedColumns` separate (`extras` director of the `dataTables` zip file).

Comment: @t.niese- That worked. Please post as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FixedColumns` is listed as plugin on their [download page](http://datatables.net/download/) .

So depending if you have a *full featured* build or not you would need to load the js file for `FixedColumns` separate (is included in the `extras` director of the `dataTables` zip file)